# my application work on emulator but it doesn't work on my phone

Tags: android, mobile

the error what i face it is when i run this application on the emulator on the android studio all thing is fine and run well, but when i connect my phone and try to run the application on it this is the error what i face it...

```
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode 
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2  
(port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
W/System.err:     at 
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
W/System.err:     at   
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
W/System.err:     at    
com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
W/System.err:     at    
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket
(SocketConnecto    r.java:434)
W/System.err:at
      com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectCleartext
 (SocketConnecto     r.java:105)
 W/System.err:
 at          com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1331)
 W/System.err:
 at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1410)
 W/System.err:
 at    com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner
 (OkHttpClient.java:128)
 W/System.err:     at   
 com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection
 (HttpEngine.java:466)
  W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect
  (HttpEngine.java:447)
  W/System.err:     at 
 com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest

 (HttpEngine.java:353)
  W/System.err:     at   
  com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute
  (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:476)
  W/System.err:     at     
  com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect
  (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118)
   W/System.err:     at
   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream
   (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:249)
   W/System.err:     at
   com.example.win10user.project.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground
   (BackgroundWorker.java:46)
   W/System.err:     at
  com.example.win10user.project.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground
 (BackgroundWorker.java:21)
   W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
   W/System.err:     at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run
  (FutureTask.java:237)
   W/System.err:     at   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run
   (AsyncTask.java:234)
    W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
     W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed:
     ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
     W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
     W/System.err:     at   
     libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
     W/System.err:     at 
       libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
     W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
     W/System.err:  ... 23 more
     D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.win10user.project, PID: 10042
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
    method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null        
   object reference
                  at  
   com.example.win10user.project.BackgroundWorker.onPostExecute
    (BackgroundWorker.java:120)
                  at 
    com.example.win10user.project.BackgroundWorker.onPostExecute
    (BackgroundWorker.java:21)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
                  at      android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage
       (AsyncTask.java:668)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main
       (ActivityThread.java:7229)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at         
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
       (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
      (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
      I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10042 SIG: 9
      Application terminated.
```

this is the backgroundWorker.java activity
    package com.example.win10user.project;

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>  {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String myURL = "http://10.0.2.2:80/";
    String login_url = myURL+"login.php";
    String register_url = myURL+"sign.php";
    if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {

            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                                +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else  if(type.equals("register")) {
        try {
            String password = params[1];
            String name = params[2];
            String email = params[3];

            URL url = new URL(register_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")+"&"
                              +URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                              +URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   if(result.equals("Insert Successful")) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Done!! Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);

    }else if(result.equals("This Email")) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "This Email have an account!!! please Sign Up with another Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else if(result.equals("login")){

        Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(context,HomePage.class);
        context.startActivity(i);

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Email Or Password is Incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

and this is the Main.java activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
EditText EmailEt, PasswordEt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EmailEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    PasswordEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
}
public void OnLogin(View view) {
    String username = EmailEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
        EmailEt.setError("Please Enter  our Email");
        return;
    }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        PasswordEt.setError("Please Enter Your Password");
        return;
    }else {
        String type = "login";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
    }
}

public void Register(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


}
```

and this is the signup.java activity

```
public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText PasswordEt,NameEt,EmailEt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    PasswordEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    NameEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    EmailEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
}
public void OnSubmit(View view) {
    String str_pass = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
    String str_name     = NameEt.getText().toString();
    String str_email    = EmailEt.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(str_name)) {
        NameEt.setError("Please Enter Your Name");
        return;
    }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(str_pass)) {
        PasswordEt.setError("Please Enter Your Password");
        return;
    }  else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(str_email)) {
        EmailEt.setError("Please Enter Your Email");
        return;
    }else if(!isValidEmaillId(EmailEt.getText().toString().trim())){
   EmailEt.setError("Please Enter A valid Email Like  'email@example.com'");
        return;
    }else {
         String type = "register";
         BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
         backgroundWorker.execute(type, str_pass, str_name, str_email);
     }
}

public void Return(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Signup.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private boolean isValidEmaillId(String email){

return Pattern.compile("^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]  {2,}))@"
            + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
            + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
        + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$").matcher(email).matches();
}

}
```

Comment: Your doInBackground() resulting NULL. Do a null check in onpostexecute. And Its unable to reach 10.0.2.2. Check why?

Comment: Have you checked that your phone is connected to the same wifi network that has this address http://10.0.2.2:80/?

Answer (score 0):

Application works on Emulator because `http://10.0.2.2:80/` is accessible from it, which is the host machine special address for emulator.

If you want this app to run on devices too, then update the address to your machines's IP and make sure both the machine and device are on same network (Or use domain name if the service is hosted somewhere on public network too).

Answer (score 0):

http://10.0.2.2:80 is meant only for your emulator. You would need to host your PHP files someplace for it to work with your device.